# Generate Reports and Dashboards by getting data from External Services

Tags: lightning-experience, dashboard, reports-api, custom-reports

I have a requirement where the users want to generate Reports and Dashboards by getting data from external web services. This data is not stored in Salesforce. We will have to call the webservice, get the data and use it to generate view only reports.

Currently, I'm calling the webservice and displaying it on a Lightning component tab on record page but now I have to generate report out of it.

My question is, Is that possible? Can we generate reports and dashboards from the data that is not stored in Salesforce?

Any help is appreciated. Please advise a solution or point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There's a feature known as [External Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_object_define.htm&type=5). External Objects allows you to define a connection to data that exists outside Salesforce. You can run reports and create dashboards based on this data. However, this is a paid feature, meaning you'll have to shell out extra money in order to use this feature. Contact your account executive for pricing. You get this feature for free in a Developer Edition org, so you can preview it before you decide to commit to a purchasing decision.